# Multiple locations within a folder hierarchy to run SCons from

Tags: scons

So far, I've only seen examples of running SCons in the same folder as the single SConstruct file resides. Let's say my project structure is like:

- src/*.(cpp|h)
- tools/mytool/*.(cpp|h)

What I'd like is to be able to run 'scons' at the root and also inside tools/mytool. The latter compiles only mytool. Is this possible with SCons?

I assume it involves creating another SConstruct file. I've made another one: tools/mytool/SConstruct

I made it contain only:

```
SConscript('../../SConstruct')
```

and I was thinking of doing Import('env mytoolTarget') and calling Default(mytoolTarget), but running it with just the above runs in the current directory instead of from the root, so the include paths are broken.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I believe you would only want multiple SConstruct files if you want to build multiple independent products. Otherwise you want to avoid the "recursive make problem" and have a hierarchy of SConscript files under a single SConstruct and run with -u as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-u` option to do this. From any subdirectory, `scons -u` will search upwards in the directory tree for an `SConstruct` file.